# Conditional formatting based on a value, if value is found then format all the column

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have this table on excel that I would like to color when the value "do" is found... The "hard part" (for me) is to color also the rows that are under that value, untile row n.39

Here is a picture of my current table:

[image: demonstration]

Here is the code I used to create the Table so far...

```
Sub FillCal()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim contatore As Integer
contatatore = -1
Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
Dim prova As Integer
Dim rngMerge As Range, rngCell As Range, mergeVal As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim GiornoSingolo As String
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") ' Change Sheet1 to your worksheet

Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("D2:XZ39").Clear

strInterval = "d"
StartD = Foglio1.Cells(2, 2)
EndD = Foglio1.Cells(3, 2)
For Row = 4 To EndD - StartD
    'Cells(4, Row) = Format(StartD + Row - 1, "d mmmm yyyy")
    contatore = DatePart(strInterval, StartD + Row - 1)

    Cells(3, Row).NumberFormat = 0
    Cells(3, Row).Value = contatore
    Cells(3, Row).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(3, Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(3, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1

    GiornoSingolo = Format(StartD + Row - 1, "ddd")

    prova = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(StartD + Row - 1, 2)

    'Cells(6, Row).NumberFormat = 0
    Cells(4, Row) = Left(GiornoSingolo, 2)
    Cells(4, Row).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(4, Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(4, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    'GiornoSingolo = Left(StartD + Row - 1, "ddd")
    'GiornoSingolo = Left(Text(StartD + Row - 1, "ddd"), 1)
    'Cells(6, Row) = Left(StartD + Row - 1, "DDD")
    Cells(2, Row) = Format(StartD + Row - 1, "MMMM' yy")

    Cells(2, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(5, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(6, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(7, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(8, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(9, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(10, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(11, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(12, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(13, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(14, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(15, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(16, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(17, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(18, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(19, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(20, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(21, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(22, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(23, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(24, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(25, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(26, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(27, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(28, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(29, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(30, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(31, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(32, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(33, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(34, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(35, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(36, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(37, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(38, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Cells(39, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1

Next Row



Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is the output :
[image: Output]

Comment: Have you considered using a Formula Condition and `COUNTIF` to check the cells above?  (Remember `$A$1` is Absolute Position, but `A1` is Relative)

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new in coding and can't understand how to check values that are empty, like value "do" ok I can check it, but how to do with the other ones that are blank?

Comment: just mark the complete arrea, where the color can occur `$D$4:$AE$39` -> conditional formatting -> formula -> `=D$4="do"`. (For your sample output) And don't forget to change the color. I'm often wondering why nothing happens, but i just forgot to change the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code (I used a (for loop) for a better coding experience ) :

```
Sub FillCal()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim contatore As Integer
contatatore = -1
Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
Dim prova As Integer
Dim rngMerge As Range, rngCell As Range, mergeVal As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim GiornoSingolo As String
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") ' Change Sheet1 to your worksheet

Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("D2:XZ39").Clear

strInterval = "d"
StartD = Worksheets("Foglio1").Cells(2, 2)
EndD = Worksheets("Foglio1").Cells(3, 2)
For Row = 4 To EndD - StartD
    'Cells(4, Row) = Format(StartD + Row - 1, "d mmmm yyyy")
    contatore = DatePart(strInterval, StartD + Row - 1)

    Cells(3, Row).NumberFormat = 0
    Cells(3, Row).Value = contatore
    Cells(3, Row).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(3, Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(3, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1

    GiornoSingolo = Format(StartD + Row - 1, "ddd")

    prova = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(StartD + Row - 1, 2)

    'Cells(6, Row).NumberFormat = 0
    Cells(4, Row) = Left(GiornoSingolo, 2)
    Cells(4, Row).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(4, Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(4, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    'GiornoSingolo = Left(StartD + Row - 1, "ddd")
    'GiornoSingolo = Left(Text(StartD + Row - 1, "ddd"), 1)
    'Cells(6, Row) = Left(StartD + Row - 1, "DDD")
    Cells(2, Row) = Format(StartD + Row - 1, "MMMM' yy")

    For ii = 2 To 39
        Cells(ii, Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
    Next ii

    If Cells(4, Row).Text = "do" Then
        For i = 4 To 39
            Cells(i, Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 9
        Next i
    End If
Next Row



Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To colour all cells in Column A which have the value `"do"`, and all cells below them, use the following Formula condition:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,"do")>0
```

This will automatically 'stretch' down, so that in cell A5 it will become `=COUNTIF(A$1:A5,"do")>0`, in cell A11 it's `=COUNTIF(A$1:A11,"do")>0`, and so on.

**HOWEVER!**  Looking at your images, the row with `"do"` in it will always be the same, row 4.

So, select the range `D4:AE39`, and use the following Formula Condition instead:

```
=(D$4="do")
```

As this is goes to the right, the *column* will update.  However, because of the `$` symbol, the *row* will always stay as 4